# Solr OR between Block Join expressions

Tags: solr

Does anyone know how to make a query in Solr between a block join expression and a "regular" expression? For example like this:

```
{!parent which="content_t:customer"}(content_t:order AND orderDate_dt:[* TO 2016-01-13T00:00:00Z])
```

OR

```
customerType=VIP
```

It seems to me like I have tried all combinations and alternativs with "q" and "fq" parameters, but there is always something giving me a query error. By default we have AND between fq parameters, and I guess q.op does not change that?

I have also tried to create a corresponding NOT AND query, which logically is the same. This works for queries that do not contain block join expressions. E.g., this is not valid:

```
fq=-{!parent which="content_t:customer"}(content_t:order AND orderDate_dt:[* TO 2016-01-13T00:00:00Z])
```

but this is:

```
-(customerType=VIP)
```

We are using Solr 5.2.1. Can someone please help?